# Windows Disk is not accessible (happened during permission change)

Tags: windows, permissions

I have a non-system partition (technically, HW RAID array with two partitions - the one in question is encrypted with Bitlocker) that is no longer accessible in Windows. I was adding permissions to the drive when the system crashed. Now, the drive is inaccessible to users whose permission wasn't being changed.

The HW RAID array controller reports the disk is healthy and Windows Disk Management sees the device. Bitlocker will unlock without a problem.

If I right-click the drive letter, the SECURITY tab is no longer present. Further, if I try to scan for errors, the disk reports that the disk is inaccessible. I have also tried `takeown /f e:\ /a r` as administrator but receive the message `ERROR: The parameter is incorrect`.

As the hardware appears healthy (the second partition on the same array is fully accessible), BitLocker unlocks the drive, and the drive ran into this problem while changing permissions, this seems likes a permission problem. However, I have never encountered a permission problem where the security tab has vanished and Windows reports the disk as inaccessible (despite looking healthy in the Disk Management).

So, please offer me some guidance as I am at a complete loss at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `takeown` command is incorrect. It should be: `takeown /F "e:\" /A /R /D Y`. Run it from CMD as Administrator.

Comment: Thanks. I still receive the same error.

Comment: Run `chkdsk`, *after* ensuring good backups. Why did it crash in the first place?